# calculating students avg using loop

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32, masm32

This program should calculate the avg grades of students. 
I'm using a loop for the user to input 5 grades.
I tried to keep the div part outside the loop, but it did not work.
I had to put it inside the loop although logically doesn't make since and it always prints 1.

here is the code:

```
include irvine32.inc

; Write a MASM program that calculates the avg grade of a student(Five grades are inputted by the user).

.data

mesg byte "     *********This program calculates average grades of students *********", 0dh, 0ah, 0
mesg1 byte "Enter 5 grades: ", 0dh, 0ah, 0
mesg2 byte "The average grade is: ", 0dh, 0ah, 0

grade1 dword ?
grade2 dword ?
grade3 dword ?
grade4 dword ?
grade5 dword ?


.code
main proc

mov eax, 0

mov edx, OFFSET mesg
call writestring

mov edx, OFFSET mesg1
call writestring

mov ecx, 5

myLoop :

call readint
mov grade1, eax
call readint
mov grade2, eax
call readint
mov grade3, eax
call readint
mov grade4, eax
call readint
mov grade5, eax

add eax, grade1
add eax, grade2
add eax, grade3
add eax, grade4
mov grade5, eax

call writeint

call dumpregs

    LOOP myLoop

mov edx, OFFSET mesg2
call writestring

mov eax, grade5
mov cl, 5
sub edx, edx
div cl

call writeint
call dumpregs


exit
main endp
end main
```

---

calculating avg, with the `div` inside the loop:

```
include irvine32.inc

; Write a MASM program that calculates the avg grade of a student(Five grades are inputted by the user).

.data

mesg byte "     *********This program calculates average grades of students *********", 0dh, 0ah, 0
mesg1 byte "Enter 5 grades: ", 0dh, 0ah, 0
mesg2 byte "The average grade is: ", 0dh, 0ah, 0

grade1 dword ?
grade2 dword ?
grade3 dword ?
grade4 dword ?
grade5 dword ?


.code
main proc

    mov eax, 0

    mov edx, OFFSET mesg
    call writestring

    mov edx, OFFSET mesg1
    call writestring

    mov ecx, 5

myLoop:
    call readint
    mov grade1, eax
    call readint
    mov grade2, eax
    call readint
    mov grade3, eax
    call readint
    mov grade4, eax
    call readint
    mov grade5, eax

    add eax, grade1
    add eax, grade2
    add eax, grade3
    add eax, grade4
    mov grade5, eax

    call writeint

    call dumpregs


    mov edx, OFFSET mesg2
    call writestring

    mov eax, grade5
    mov ebx, 5
    sub edx, edx
    div ebx

    call writeint
    call dumpregs

    LOOP myLoop


    exit
main endp
end main
```

Comment: So it doesn't work *inside* the loop, either.  Why do you need a loop at all, since you have explicit code to read each of the 5 grades?

Comment: It's my professor's instructions

Comment: I have a very strong suspicion you should be using [] to read from memory for grade1 through 5.  I also feel that you should be using only the grade1 label and incrementing a register every time through the loop to read it in as an array - which is what your instructor wanted...

Comment: @MichaelDorgan thanks a lot, Micheal! I'll actually do it using array as u indicated since i was thinking of it but i don't know why the professor asks not to use an array, but i'll do what is logic and submitted. Thanks a gain!

Comment: If you only need to compute the average, you don't need an array: once you've added an entered number into the sum (which you can do immediately after reading it), you don't need it any more.

Comment: @ScottHunter that what i tried to do but i didnt work! I put the calculating avg. instructions outside the loop and i did not work. When i put it inside the loop, it gives me five chances to add five grades, i mean adding five grades five times total of 25 times in this case the avg. is calculated but NOT when i keep it outside the loop which is very weird. Why it is not calculating the avg when i keep the calculating avg instructions outside the loop? this is what confuses me. Thanks!

Comment: If you read 5 values (grade1..grade5) and do that 5 times, why are you surprised to be reading 25 values in total?  And if you want help with a different version of the code, you have to post *that* version.

Comment: @ScottHunter bcoz as I said, when i keep calculating instructions outside the loop, it does not count the average even once! How it can work inside the loop but not outside?!

Comment: Please show the code w/ the div inside the loop.

Comment: @ScottHunter I just did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> add eax, grade1
> add eax, grade2
> add eax, grade3
> add eax, grade4
> mov grade5, eax
> ```

The code above has 2 problems. You didn't clear the `EAX` register at the start and you forgot to add in the 5th grade. Correct it like:

```
mov eax, grade1  <-- MOV = start with a clean EAX
add eax, grade2
add eax, grade3
add eax, grade4
add eax, grade5
mov grade5, eax
```

---

> ```
> mov eax, grade5
> mov cl, 5
> sub edx, edx
> div cl
> ```

To calculate the average you want to divide the dword in `EAX` by 5, but by writing `div cl` you only divide the word in `AX`. Best use the following:

```
mov eax, grade5
mov ecx, 5
sub edx, edx    ;Will divide EDX:EAX by ECX
div ecx         ;Quotient in EAX
```

---

> I had to put it inside the loop although logically doesn't make sense

It does make sense when inputting 5 grades each for 5 students.
What doesn't make sense is the *myLoop* loop on the 1st program. It'll only give an average for the last set of 5 grades!

Answer (score 0):

The only obvious problem with your second version is that you don't use `grade5`.  Maybe try `add grade5, eax`, instead of `mov grade5, eax`, but that won't leave the sum in `eax` for WriteInt.

Use a debugger and single-step through your code.  If there's anything you still can't figure out, update your question with what exactly you want your code to do, and what *exactly* it's actually doing.  And what instruction is the problem, if you can narrow it down with a debugger.